# Failing to establish a gRPC connection after deploying my services on a server

Tags: c#, asp.net, networking, grpc

I have developed an application in a simple three-tier architecture written in C# using .NET 5 and  gRPC. I developed and tested my work locally using localhost as domain. I know that my work itself works perfectly fine locally and now I wanted to do the next step and deployed it on a server.

I don't have much server experience, so there might be a noob issue on my end. Here is what I did:

1. Before putting my server application (C#, .NET 5, gRPC with ASP.NET) on the server, I edited the launchSettings.json as shown below using the IP address of my server. I made sure all file paths used in my server application are valid on the server.
2. I added exceptions to Windows Firewall to all any connection from or to my server application and explicitly did the same for the Advanced Windows Firewall settings.

Trouble shooting I did:

1. I added log output to the beginning of each available gRPC service in my server application. There are no logs written, which implies that no call ever reached the server application.
2. I pinged my server from my personal computer and I could ping the IP address with a ping of 80ms. That means, the server itself is available over the internet. (The physical server is rented from a host in another country.)
3. Since I did not change the ports on either the server app or the client app, I can assume that I do not have to adjust any Firewall settings on my computer (location of the client app).
4. Reading, googling, crying, ...

**launchSettings.json**

```
{
    "iisSettings": {
        "windowsAuthentication": false,
        "anonymousAuthentication": true,
        "iisExpress": {
            "applicationUrl": "https://MY_ACTUAL_IP_ADDRESS:49901/",
            "sslPort": 0
        }
    },
    "profiles": {
        MY_ACTUAL_PROJECT_NAME: {
            "commandName": "Project"
        }
    }
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
    "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Microsoft": "Warning",
            "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
    },
    "AllowedHosts": "*",
    "Kestrel": {
        "EndpointDefaults": {
            "Protocols": "Http2"
        }
    }
}
```

**Starting my services (server app)**

```
using GalacticCrew2Server.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

namespace GalacticCrew2Server
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc(options =>
            {
                options.MaxReceiveMessageSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
                options.MaxSendMessageSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024;
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<AuthenticationService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<BugReportService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<GalaxyService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<TradingService>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**Connecting to services and calling one (client app)**

```
_grpcChannel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://MY_ACTUAL_IP_ADDRESS:5001/", new GrpcChannelOptions()
{
    MaxReceiveMessageSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024,
    MaxSendMessageSize = 16 * 1024 * 1024
});

_authenticationClient = new AuthenticationClient(_grpcChannel);
_bugReportsClient = new BugReportsClient(_grpcChannel);
_galaxyClient = new GalaxyClient(_grpcChannel);
_tradingClient = new TradingClient(_grpcChannel);

// ...

var response = _authenticationClient.Authenticate(new AuthenticateRequest()
{
    // Filling out parameters
});
```

Comment: Try using `https://0.0.0.0:5001` for the server and then see if the client connect. If you can, there's likely something sitting between the server and the internet. If you can't connect, try using telnet to confirm whether it's accepting the connection. If you can't telnet, it's likely that the server has incoming connections blocked.

Comment: I tried it, but it did not work. I also opened the ports excplicitly in Windows Firewall in addition to enabling the entire server app. Also, I made sure the firewall of the vServer is open on these ports. I could not ping the ports with telnet however...